# Does water damage explain this issue?

Tags: damage, water

I posted previously that the hot water button (PA in red) no longer causes the hot water solenoid (Eac in red) to dispense water. It now causes the left coffee group solenoid (G1 in green) to dispense water which should normally only be the case when its buttons (Z1 in green) are pushed.

Today I discovered a couple of water drops dripping on the board (brown square on schematic, between 3rd resistor and 3rd cap on picture). Is there any way water damage to this area could explain the mentioned behaviour? If so, how would you recommend checking the board for the specific issue and what can be a likely solution?

[image: schematics]
[image: board]

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be the output relay section and it's unlikely that you'd see that effect from water in that area, at least without a lot more damage being visually apparent.

Suggest you remove the board carefully and look elsewhere, particularly where connections are dense and components perhaps are surface-mounted. It's quite possible that water damage has caused this issue, it's just more likely to be elsewhere.